# How do I use OAuth2 in a command line tool to access an application hosted on Google Appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

I have an application hosted on google app-engine (http://spititan.appspot.com). I also have a command line tool to access that application through ClientLogin. The code snippet is as following:

```
138   # get an AuthToken from Google accounts
139   auth_uri = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin'
140   authreq_data = urllib.parse.urlencode({ "Email":   email_address,
141                                     "Passwd":  password,
142                                     "service": "ah",
143                                     "source":  appname,
144                                     "accountType": "HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE" })
145   request = urllib.request.Request(auth_uri, data=authreq_data)
146   response = opener.open(request)
147   response_body = str(response.read(), 'utf-8')
148   response_dict = dict(x.split("=") for x in response_body.split("\n") if x)
149   return response_dict["Auth"]

...
...

112   # Send the auth token to the AppEngine to login
113   continue_location = "http://localhost/"
114   args = {"continue": continue_location, "auth": auth_token}
115   host = "spititan.appspot.com" % appname 
116   url = "https://spititan/_ah/login?%s" % urllib.parse.urlencode(args)
...
...
```

This tool works fine for me for quite a while with minor annoy that I need to provide password every a few days.  I noticed that OAuth2 is the current recommended way to authenticate, so I managed to learn to use it and write the following code snippet by following the doc (http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/wiki/OAuth2):

```
 59   storage = oauth2client.file.Storage(
 60       os.path.join(FLAGS.data_dir, 'confidential.dat'))
 61 
 62   credentials = storage.get()
 63 
 64   if credentials is None or credentials.invalid == True:
 65     flow = oauth2client.client.OAuth2WebServerFlow(
 66         client_id='<xxxxx>',
 67         client_secret='<xxxxx>',
 68         scope='<xxxxx>',
 69         user_agent='<xxxx>')
 70 
 71     credentials = oauth2client.tools.run(flow, storage)
 72 
 73   http = httplib2.Http(cache=".cache")
 74   http = credentials.authorize(http)
```

My understanding is 'client_id' and 'client_secret' are acquired when I register the application, user_agent is a free format string, the problem is: what should I put in the 'scope'?  I tried http://spititan.appspot.com/spititan but got no luck, does anybody have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.admin'`. 
I was looking for appengine scope too once and found it in here:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py#143

If you're trying to do something other than logging in as an admin, this won't work. AFAIK GAE supports ClientLogin, OAuth 1.0 and OpenID ATM. So, no OAuth 2.0. I wonder when they will though.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. That scope is the OAuth scope that authorizes an application to administer a user's App Engine applications, for example by passing the refresh token to appcfg.py as described in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#oauth

Comment: I don't think this is right either although I did not try the suggestion yet.  I think at least the scope URL will mention the appid 'spititan' somehow.

Comment: @JasonHall Right, that scope is for an app admins authorization.

Comment: @spititan The scope, in fact, should not mention your app. What it does mention is what your app intends to do with the authorization a user gives to the app during so-called OAuth "dance". AFAIK App Engine ATM supports either Google Accounts, OpenID or OAuth 1.0.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I will keep using the current ClientLogin code. Thanks.

Comment: You are my hero! I was searching for the GAE scope but it was nowhere documented. Thank you!